# Find all words that start with @ sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following Javascript function that finds all matches of a set of words inside a contenteditable div:

```
var words = ['oele', 'geel', 'politie', 'foo bar'];

function markWords() {
    var html = div.html().replace(/<\/?strong>/gi, ''),
        text = html.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
        exp;
    $.each(words, function(i, word) {
        exp = new RegExp('\\b(' + word + ')\\b', 'gi');
        html = html.replace(exp, function(m) {
console.log('WORD MATCH:', m);
            return '<strong>' + m + '</strong>';
        });
    });
    //html = html.replace('&nbsp;', ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    div.html(html);
}
```

How can I modify it so that It marks all those words, only in the cases that they start with the at sign `@`? For example, it should match `@foo bar`, etc.

[Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/kMs2N/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
exp = new RegExp('\\b(' + word + ')\\b', 'gi');
```

to

```
exp = new RegExp('@\\b(' + word + ')\\b', 'gi');
```

it will match contents like `@politie` or `@foo bar`.

Comment: Is that where you intended to put the `@`? Remember `\ ` has its own meaning in string literal.

Comment: @squint that was a typo, fixed now!

Comment: @enb081 try the fixed version, I accidentally make a typo, when typing in code. Should have copy/pasted ;)

Comment: That works better, but it'll also match if there's a non-word-break just before the `@`. Like `"test@foo bar"` But maybe OP wants that.